# SAPUI5 FormContainer field vertical spacing

Tags: xml, forms, sapui5

I am using SAPUI5 XML view and have a form with formContainers and FormElements. My form is displaying correctly except that the spacing between lines on the form is too big...seems close to spacing is close to 2. I have the form in a gird and have added vSpacing="0.5" but it doesn't seem to be following that. Here is my XML - some portions omitted to be brief.

```
  <l:Grid
     defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12"
     hSpacing="0.5"
     vSpacing="0.5"
     width="auto">
    <l:content>

        <f:Form id="FormChange354"
            minWidth="1024"
            maxContainerCols="2"
            editable="true"
            >

            <f:layout>
                <f:ResponsiveGridLayout
                    labelSpanL="3"
                    labelSpanM="3"
                    emptySpanL="4"
                    emptySpanM="4"
                    columnsL="1"
                    columnsM="1" />
            </f:layout>
            <f:formContainers>
                <f:FormContainer title="Part I">
                    <f:formElements>
                        <f:FormElement label="Products">
                            <f:fields>
                                <Input   editable= "false" value="{classProducts}"/>
                            </f:fields>
                        </f:FormElement>
                        <f:FormElement label="Partners">
                            <f:fields>
                                <Input  editable= "false" value="{classPartners}"/>
                            </f:fields>
                        </f:FormElement>
                </f:FormContainer>
            </f:formContainers>
        </f:Form>
</l:content>
```

This is how it is displaying....
[image]

How can I change the spacing between lines? Also, can I change the size of the title ('Part I') to be smaller - would any style apply?

Answer (score 2):

well I think I resolved this by changing the form to not be editable. When I changed it to 'false' the spacing went to normal 1 line spacing.

Comment: Exactly. The `editable` property is used for alignments. If you´re in `editable` mode the form assigns more space for Input controls. In non-editable mode this space is not assigned anymore and the form is therefore more compact.